Passing boolean parameter in Azure CLI Devops extension
We have a devops template which contains boolean parameters like:
parameters:
- name: Foo
  type: boolean
  default: true

When we run command az pipelines run, we could not pass boolean value through --parameters option.

If we try --parameters Foo=$false, it actually transfers "Foo": "False" to the backend.
If we try --parameters Foo=false, it actually transfers "Foo": "false" to the backend.


@ZiyangLiu-MSFT - please stop posting comments asking people if their answer works, or for follow-up questions. This is entirely unneeded (and keep in mind: this is not an official support site, paid or free, and has no SLA and no obligation for any type of response); best not to give the wrong impression and wrong expectations.

Agreed with @RithwikBojja, you see it because it's a JSON output. Actually, the pipeline takes it as Boolean value in backend. You can easily verify this by passing a string to your boolean parameter.
parameters:
- name: FooBool
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: FooString
  type: string
  default: false

When run az pipelines run --name TestBoolParemeter --parameters FooBool=string, the pipeline will not be triggered with the following error:

When run az pipelines run --name TestBoolParemeter --parameters FooString=string, the pipeline can be triggered successfully.


fyi - Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

You are doing it right it will pass false and the pipeline takes it as Boolean value only in backend. It shows  "Test": "false"   for us in Azure ClI as CLI provides a json output, but in backend it takes it as Bollean itself. Below is my approach:
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

parameters:
  - name: Test
    type: boolean
    default: true

jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
      - script: echo "Hello Rithwik Bojja, The value of Test param is ${{ parameters.Test }}"
        displayName: 'Rithwik is Printing Bollean value'

CLI:
az devops configure --defaults organization=https://dev.azure.com/test  project="Rith Proj name"
az pipelines run --name rithtest88 --parameters Test=false

Output:
It just provides you json output and in backend takes it as boolean as in yaml we have said the type is boolean.


For further you can test it like below(like if else):

Output:
Because I provided Boolean value false, it is printing false.

